# Fonts are different in vim under byobu compared to vim under screen and normal terminal

Tags: fonts, gnu-screen, ubuntu-16.04, .bash-profile, byobu

The font shows different in vim under normal bash and vim under byobu. Attached is a screenshot.

This is the default byobu setting as soon as I do an apt install byobu.
However, the font looks normal when run under screen.

So my assumption is that byobu overwrites the default terminal profile w.r.t. fonts.

Can someone help me get the same font (non-bold syntax highlights and strings) in vim under byobu as they appear in normal Ubuntu 16.04 terminal and under screen?

I tried googling around, however I don't think I know the right keywords to get the answer online.

I want the font as on the right (running outside byobu) as seen below (you will have to zoom to normal resolution to get the font difference!).

[image: I want the font as on the right (running outside byobu)]